# Mapped type with nested keys

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Is it possible to write a mapped type using a product of nested keys to generate keys?

This is what I want to obtain:

```
type Nested = {
  foo: string;
  bar: { baz: number; };
  squick: { squeck: string; squawk: boolean; };
  garble: { gobble: string; };
};
type Unnested = Flatten<Nested, 'bar' | 'squick'>;

// Should be equivalent to:
type Unnested = {
  foo: string;
  'bar.baz': number;
  'squick.squeck': string;
  'squick.squawk': boolean;
  garble: { gobble: string; };
};
```

I know I can do this:

```
type Flatten<T, K extends string & keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {
  [k in K as `${k}.${string & keyof T[k]}`]: T[k][string & keyof T[k]];
};
```

But then each resulting mapped property's type is a union of all the possible property types in the nested object (i.e. in the previous example both `squick.squeck` and `squick.squawk` have type `string | boolean`).
What I actually want is that each resulting property preserves its original type.

Actually, this solution can't even restrict the inner properties to the children of the outer properties from which they descend (i.e. it will also generate `squick.baz`, `bar.squeck` and `bar.squawk`).

My intuition is that, for each outer property, I need to "loop" on each inner property, thus creating a product.

Is there a TypeScript notation that will allow me to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like an odd special case to require keys at the top level. Presumably every level below the top needs to flatten every property recursively, so you really want a full `Flatten` and then you can `Pick` and `Omit` at the top level if you need it.  Or is it possible that at nested levels you might decide not to flatten something whose parent was already flattened?

Comment: Actually, I just plan on using one level of flattening, if it's simpler, of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type Flatten<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: (
    x: NonNullable<T[K]> extends infer V
      ? V extends object
        ? V extends readonly any[]
          ? Pick<T, K>
          : Flatten<V> extends infer FV
          ? {
              [P in keyof FV as `${Extract<K, string | number>}.${Extract<P, string | number>}`]: FV[P]
            }
          : never
        : Pick<T, K>
      : never
  ) => void
} extends Record<keyof T, (y: infer O) => void>
  ? O extends unknown
    ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }
    : never
  : never
```

Comment: Mind giving us an explanation of how it works?

Comment: This is mighty. It just misses a `K` type parameter on the `Flatten` type, to select which properties to flatten. It is doable (I managed to do do it, so it must be... :-), maybe you'd need to drop array types from the equation... would you mind adding it? It also is recursive, which is overkill form my purposes, but nonetheless very interesting.